# Can't get 2 separate classes to interact with each other without using Global variables in Ruby- Bank Program

Tags: ruby

New user and first time poster here!  I'm new to Ruby and am working on what "should" be a simple banking program in which I have to come up with the code to produce a given output and the method calls.  I seemed to be moving along nicely but have hit a major roadblock in which my 2 classes (bank and person) aren't communicating with one another properly.  I came up with a solution using global variables in my person class so that the bank class could access it but then saw somewhere that I should avoid global variables.  I'm currently trying to get the classes to communicate without the use of the global variables and it seems that whenever I call my "open_account" method, that method is not able to pull in the name (@pname) from the Person class.

I've looked all over for the past 8-9 days and even bought another Ruby book, but none of them seem to have an example/tutorial about how to directly make 2 separate classes interact with each other without them inheriting from one another or using modules and such.  I just want the Bank class to be able to use the Name and Cash, etc. from the Person class when I call the different bank methods.

I haven't really pushed on trying to finish the deposit and transfer methods as I'd like to resolve the communication issue so you can ignore those 2 methods in the bank class.  The expected output is commented at the end of what I currently have.  Any advice on how I'd be able to accomplish this?  I'm very new to Ruby and think I'm getting an understanding of it but still acknowledge I'm still very rough around the edges.  Thanks in advance!

Oh and one last thing, when I used the global variables to access my person objects, I would get the last person object created being output in **all** of the places where I expected each of the different person objects created.  This obviously isn't the case since I'm going away from the global variable use, but I'm still curious as to why it happened?  Thanks!

**Update:**
My updated code is below the original code but my balances seem to be a single balance instead of each person having their own.  The output I'm getting is below the updated code.

```
class Bank

  def initialize(bname, withdrawal=0, deposit=0, transfer=0)
    @bname = bname
    @withdrawal = withdrawal
    @deposit = deposit
    @transfer = transfer
    puts "#{@bname} bank was just created."
  end

  def open_account(pname)
    puts "#{@pname}, thanks for opening an account at #{@bname}!"
  end

  def withdrawal(amount)
    @balance -= amount
    puts "#{@pname} withdrew $#{amount} from #{@bname}.  #{@pname} has #{@balance}.  #{@pname}'s account has #{@balance}."
  end

  def deposit(pname, amount)
    @balance += amount
    puts "#{@pname} deposited $#{amount} to #{@bname}.  #{@pname} has #{@balance}.  #{@pname}'s account has #{@balance}."
  end


  def transfer(pname, bname, amount)
    if @pname == pname
      @balance -= amount
      @transfer = amount
      puts "You have transferred $#{amount} from your account.  Your new balance is $#{@balance}."
    else
      puts "Incorrect username."
    end
  end
end

class Person

  def initialize(pname, cash)
    @pname = pname
    @cash = cash
    puts "Hi, #{@pname}.  You have #{@cash}!"
  end

end

chase = Bank.new("JP Morgan Chase")
wells_fargo = Bank.new("Wells Fargo")
person1 = Person.new("John", 1000)
person2 = Person.new("Lloyd", 5000)
chase.open_account(person1)
chase.open_account(person2)
wells_fargo.open_account(person1)
wells_fargo.open_account(person2)
#chase.deposit(person1, 200)
#chase.deposit(person2, 350)
#chase.withdrawal(person1, 500)

=begin #What should be ouput
JP Morgan Chase bank was just created.
Wells Fargo bank was just created.
Hi, John. You have $1000!
Hi, Lloyd. You have $5000!
John, thanks for opening an account at JP Morgan Chase!
Lloyd, thanks for opening an account at JP Morgan Chase!
John, thanks for opening an account at Wells Fargo!
Lloyd, thanks for opening an account at Wells Fargo!
=end
```

******Updated Code*******

```
class Bank

  def initialize(bname, balance = 0, withdrawal=0, deposit=0, transfer=0)
    @bname = bname
    @withdrawal = withdrawal
    @deposit = deposit
    @transfer = transfer
    @balance = balance
    puts "#{@bname} bank was just created."
  end

  def open_account(name, balance = 0)
    @balance = balance
    puts "#{name}, thanks for opening an account at #{@bname}!"
  end


  def withdrawal(name, amount)
    @balance -= amount
    puts "#{name} withdrew $#{amount} from #{@bname}.  #{name} has #{@balance}.  #{name}'s account has #{@balance}."
  end

  def deposit(name, amount)
    @balance += amount
    puts "#{name} deposited $#{amount} to #{@bname}.  #{name} has #{@balance}.  #{name}'s account has #{@balance}."
  end

  def transfer(name, bname, amount)
    if name == name
      @balance -= amount
      @transfer = amount
      puts "#{name} have transfered $#{amount} from #{@bname} account to #{@bname}.  Your new balance is $#{@balance}."
    else
      puts "Incorrect username."
    end
  end
end

class Person

  attr_accessor :name, :cash
  def initialize(name, cash = 100)
    @name = name
    @cash = cash
    puts "Hi, #{name}.  You have $#{cash} on hand!"
  end

end

chase = Bank.new("JP Morgan Chase")
wells_fargo = Bank.new("Wells Fargo")
randy = Person.new("Randy", 1000)
kristen = Person.new("Kristen", 5000)
justin = Person.new("Justin", 1500)
chase.open_account('Randy')
chase.open_account('Kristen')
chase.open_account('Justin')
wells_fargo.open_account('Randy')
wells_fargo.open_account('Kristen')
chase.deposit("Randy", 200)
chase.deposit("Kristen", 350)
chase.withdrawal("Kristen", 500)
chase.transfer("Randy", wells_fargo, 100)

=begin #updated code output
JP Morgan Chase bank was just created.
Wells Fargo bank was just created.
Hi, Randy.  You have $1000 on hand!
Hi, Kristen.  You have $5000 on hand!
Hi, Justin.  You have $1500 on hand!
Randy, thanks for opening an account at JP Morgan Chase!
Kristen, thanks for opening an account at JP Morgan Chase!
Justin, thanks for opening an account at JP Morgan Chase!
Randy, thanks for opening an account at Wells Fargo!
Kristen, thanks for opening an account at Wells Fargo!
Randy deposited $200 to JP Morgan Chase.  Randy has 200.  Randy's account has 200.
Kristen deposited $350 to JP Morgan Chase.  Kristen has 550.  Kristen's account has 550.
Kristen withdrew $500 from JP Morgan Chase.  Kristen has 50.  Kristen's account has 50.
Randy have transfered $100 from JP Morgan Chase account to JP Morgan Chase.  Your new balance is $-50.
=end
```

Comment: Read this: http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html

Comment: Thanks, Uri!  I'm checking it out now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem (IMHO) is crying out for an Account object.  Account objects could be held in an array inside the Bank object.  Each Account object would contain a Person object, and that Person's balance in that bank only. The way you currently have it structured, the last person who opens an account is the only person who has an account.

Some specimen Bank methods...

```
  def open_account(person, initial_deposit = 0)
    @accounts << Account.new(person)
    puts "#{person.pname}, thanks for opening an account at #{@bname}!"
    deposit person, initial_deposit unless initial_deposit == 0
  end

  def deposit(person, amount)
    account = @accounts.select{|a| a.person == person}.first
    if account
      if person.cash < amount
        puts "#{person.pname} doesn't have that much to deposit"
      else
        account.balance += amount
        person.cash -= amount
      end
    else
      puts "no account found for #(person.pname}"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Steve!  I kept thinking the same thing as well but the instructions for the challenge are to use a bank class and a person class to interact with each other.  As I kept looking at ways to do it, creating an Account object kept seeming like a good option but I never approached it due to the restriction.  Definitely something I can possibly work in if I am allowed to venture out after completion or tinker with the overall program.

Comment: Then you could use OpenStruct to create an account entity... not a separate class but has much of the functionality.  
person = OpenStruct.new
person.name = "John"
person.balance = 0
and store the OpenStruct object in an array in the bank.

Sort of "Class lite... all the flavour, half the sugar".  Check it out here... http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html

Comment: Wow that looks pretty convenient Steve!  I'll definitely try to use that and get the balance and such needs for an account taken care of.

Comment: Steve, when you mention that the way my code is currently structured is the reason why it was showing the last person created was the only person that had an account, which part exactly is doing so.  I currently have the output set up the way that it's intended but my balance for each person seems to be taking the balance from the previous person and it's messing up my numbers. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Objects in ruby communicate with other objects by exposing methods to those objects. Instances of your `Person` class can access [instance variables](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/instancevars.html) internally, but those instance variables should not be exposed externally.

Any variable that is prefixed with an `@` sign is an instance variable, which means that `@pname` is only accessible to your person object, while `@bname` is only accessible to your bank object.

The way to access the `@pname` instance variable from your bank object is by exposing an instance method on your `Person` class for instances of your `Bank` class to call.

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def name
    @name
  end
end

john = Person.new("John Doe")
john.name # => "John Doe"
```

In this example, you are not accessing the `@name` instance variable directly, you are adding a layer of indirection around it. This is good because it allows more flexibility -- suppose rather than storing the person's entire name in one variable, you stored their first name and last name separately:

```
class Person
  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
  end

  def name
    "#{@first_name} #{@last_name}"
  end
end  

john = Person.new("John", "Doe")
john.name # => "John Doe"
```

Even though the internal implementation of storing a person's name differs from the first example, the public interface did not change: calling `person#name` returns the name of that person in both cases.

In the case where you want to expose an instance variable directly without any further manipulation, Ruby provides several [ways](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) to generate those instance methods for you without any further effort on your end. They are as follows:

1. `attr_reader`
2. `attr_writer`
3. `attr_accessor`

`attr_reader` can be used like this:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

john = Person.new("John")
john.name # => "John"
```

Under the hood it generates the following definition

```
def name
  @name
end
```

`attr_writer` can be used as follows:

```
class Person
  attr_writer :name
  def name
    @name
  end
end

john = Person.new
john.name # => nil
john.name = "John"
john.name # => "John"
```

Under the hood, `attr_writer` defined a method that allowed you to set the @name instance variable outside the context of a person object:

```
def name=(name)
  @name = name
end
```

If you wanted to create a setter method and a getter method simultaneously, you could do the following:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name
  attr_writer :name
end
```

Equivalently, you could use `attr_accessor` which creates both the getter and the setter at once:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name
end

john = Person.new
john.name # => nil
john.name = "John"
john.name # => "John"
```

The takeaway from all of this is that in Ruby, objects communicate with each other by calling methods on each other, not by accessing instance variables that do not belong to them.

Comment: This is pretty much on par with what I have kept seeing in the books and tutorials I have come across and I guess it's finally starting to stick or make sense, especially your very last sentence.  I've reworked my code and now when I run it, I get the person objects outputted on the open_account method, but they are in the weird format that's like the memory placeholder, but all of the attributes are there when I run the inspect method on them.  How would I go about turning them into the actual names of each person?

Comment: Here is my current ouput when running my reworked code with the attr_accessor:

JP Morgan Chase bank was just created.
Wells Fargo bank was just created.
Hi, John.  You have 1000!
Hi, Lloyd.  You have 5000!
Hi, Justin.  You have 1500!
#<Person:0x24ccb70>, thanks for opening an account at JP Morgan Chase!
#<Person:0x24ccaf8>, thanks for opening an account at JP Morgan Chase!
#<Person:0x24ccb70>, thanks for opening an account at Wells Fargo!
#<Person:0x24ccaf8>, thanks for opening an account at Wells Fargo!

Comment: If you want to display the person's name in your output, you can do so by saying `person.name` rather than just `person`. Alternatively, you can override Person's `to_s` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  When I ran my code this morning on another machine, the output worked as expected without me having to use a name method or overriding the to_s method.